# Getting response empty when first time calling the couch node rest api

Tags: node.js, couchbase, ottoman-node

Getting the empty response when the node api hitting first time even though the data is available in couchbase, When hitting the second time it works fine.

**This is my api for getting the data:**

```
app.get('/api/store/findByAccNo/:accountNumber',function(req,res) {
        storeMdl.findByAccountNumber(req.params.accountNumber,function(err,data){
            if (data=="") {
                var message = JSON.parse('{"status":"Failed","message":"Store does not exist"}');
                res.send(200, message);
            } else{
                var message = JSON.parse('{"status":"Success","message":' + JSON.stringify(data) + '}');
                res.send(message) 
            } 
        });

    });
```

If I am doing any thing wrong please help me to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: `console.log(err)` and `console.log(data)` ?

Comment: @mukesh sharma, console.log(data)

Comment: I meant to log the values of `err` and `data` to debug further the issue.